# c# How to modify a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a GUI application that has a ListView. It is used to show the log of the app.
In the xaml I have the following:

```
<ListView x:Name="lvStatus" Margin="5,5,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding LogView}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StatusListTemplate}">
                </ListView>
```

In the code the listView is initialized and used with a ListCollectionView:

```
public ListCollectionView LogView {get; private set; }
 ...
ObservableCollectionLog uiLogSink = new ObservableCollectionLog();
                Logger.RegisterLogSink(uiLogSink);
                LogView = new ListCollectionView(uiLogSink.Entries);
```

I would like at some point clear the ListView.  I can't just run a ListView.Clear.

Any idea how I can control my ListView?

Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a CollectionView wrapping the uiLogSynk and bind the listView to the CollectionView:

_view = new ListCollectionView(uiLogSynk);

Whenever you click the "Clear" log button you record the length of your uiLogSynk.

int startDisplayLogIndex = 0;

public void buttonClick(...)
{
    startDisplayLogIndex = uiLogSynk.Length;
}

all you have to do is to attach a filter to the _view and specify a filter function that compares the index of each element.

_view.Filter = new Predicate(ShouldDisplayLog);

public bool IsValueTruck(Object value)
{
    return (uiLogSynk.IndexOf(value) >= startDisplayLogIndex);
}

Answer (score 0):

Simply clear your bound data source.